# Structuring UITableView in VIPER

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, viper-architecture

Imagine I have a `viewForHeaderInSection` like this:

**Note:** This is currently written in MVP and I am trying to refactor it to VIPER

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        
    guard let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: DetailsSectionHeaderView.identifier) as? DetailsSectionHeaderView, 
    let section = PresenterEnum.Sections(rawValue: section), 
    section != .fourth, let presenter = presenter else { 
        return nil 
    }
        
    switch section {
        case .first:
            header.configure(StringConstants.first.localized, showButton: false, isSelected: false)
        case .second:
            let secondArray = presenter.secondArrayCount
            header.configure(StringConstants.second.localized, showButton: secondArray > 3, isSelected: presenter.isExpanded(section.rawValue))
            header.showMoreAction = { [weak self] in
                self?.handleMoreAction(tableView, in: section.rawValue)
            }
        case .third:
            let thirdCount = presenter.thirdArrayCount
            header.configure(StringConstants.third.localized, showButton: thirdArrayCount > 3, isSelected: presenter.isExpanded(section.third))
            header.showMoreAction = { [weak self] in
                self?.handleMoreAction(tableView, in: section.rawValue)
            }
        default:
            return nil
        }
        
    return header
}

private func handleMoreAction(_ tableView : UITableView, in section : Int){
    guard let presenter = presenter else {return}
        
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    let isExpanded = presenter.isExpanded(section)
        
    var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
        
    for i in presenter.minimumRowCount..<presenter.totalRowCountForSection(section){
        indexPaths.append([section, i])
    }
        
    if isExpanded{
       tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
    }else{
       tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
    }
        
    presenter.updateExpansion(section)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

`UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` are part of the `View`. But they are passive and shouldn't really request information from the `presenter`. But at the same time the HOW to display a view information belongs to the `presenter`.

Going by the definition above I can't figure out how to refactor the code below. It seems incorrect cause the logic about what the section should display is inside the view and how to handle the `showMoreAction` as well.

So my question is:
What is the "correct" way of structuring the above two methods to make it more VIPER compliant?

Answer (score 0):

1 Create protocol which allows view and presenter to pass data,
example :

```
protocol PresenterProtocol where Self: UIViewController{
   var table: UITableView {get}
}
```

2. Create weak view controller reference in the Presenter, that conforms Presenter protocol,
   expample:

   ```
   class Presenter: NSObject {

     weak var viewController: PresenterProtocol{
        didSet{
          connectVC()
        }
     }

     func connectVC(){
        self.viewController.table.delegate = self
        self.viewController.table.dataSource = self
     }
   }
   ```
3. Now when you assign tableview delegate and data source to presenter you can make an extension, example:

   ```
    extension Presenter: UITableViewDataSource , ...
    // cell for row methods ..
   ```
4. Then you should change your view(ViewController)

   ```
    class ViewController: UIViewController{
        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView?
        var presenter: Presenter?


        viewDidLoad(){
           super.viewDidLoad()
           presenter = Presenter()
           presenter.viewController = self
        }
    }
   ```

So you assigned your vc to the presenter's viewController
Now all you need is to conform your VC to PresenterProtocol

```
      extension ViewController: PresenterProtocol{
        var table: UITableView {
            return self.tableView
        }
      }
```

Now your VC is clean, and all logic contains in presenter, **sure thing it can be much easier, but I just showing the right direction**

Comment: Also you should create a builder class that instantiates presenters, iterators and other staff, and build it together as module

Comment: All actions and UI updates you can also handle through the PresenterProtocol

Comment: I understand the basics of using VIPER and how the communication happens among the various protocols/classes but I'm more curious about the specific scenarios/methods I put down in the question.

Comment: @Rikh In my experience, everyone does that differently in VIPER. I have seen completely different architectures which both claimed to be VIPER. The separation of module components was there but then everything else was different.